# What is the most recent version of GAE SDK that supports Python 2.5?

Tags: google-app-engine

We're in the process of migrating an app from python 2.5 to python 2.7.

The latest SDK (1.8.3) does not support python 2.5.

What is the most recent version of the SDK that does support python 2.5?
Please link to source if you have it.

Comment: Why not just use latest SDK and Python 2.7 ?

Comment: Deprecation announcement has been made for 2.5, so if you are undertaking a new project, start out with 2.7

Comment: Did either of you read the question body? "We're in the process of migrating an app from python 2.5 to python 2.7". So for some short time, I need to be able to use both 2.5 and 2.7

Comment: @tom Perhaps you could test each recent version of GAE SDK in Python 2.5 until you find a version that works as expected.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - yup, looks like that's what I'll need to do. thanks.

Comment: @CloseVoters This isn't a request for a library recommendation! It's a factual question about versions of a single SDK. The close reason doesn't say "Don't ask anything about a library". The reasons we don't allow library recommendations do not apply to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed google-appengine-python25-deprecation@googlegroups.com, and got the answer:

Python 2.5 apps can be run using all versions of the SDK upto and including the current (1.8.3), but:

- For SDK <= 1.7.5, the GUI by default uses a version of dev_appserver.py, which supports python 2.5 apps, so they run fine.
- For SDK > 1.7.5, the GUI by default uses the new dev_appserver.py which will not run python 2.5 apps (which gave rise to this question originally). From the command line, python 2.5 apps can be launched in SDK > 1.7.5 using the command:

  ```
  old_devappserver.py
  ```

  It may be possible to configure the GUI to use old_devappserver.py, but I dont know how to do it, and did not get guidance from Goolge on it

Answer (score 7):

From the [SDK Release Notes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes), it appears that at the very least 1.6.2 supports Python 2.5, while the most recent version to *mention* Python 2.5 is 1.8.2.

There is no mention anywhere in the release notes that GAE *no longer works* with 2.5, but instead that is deprecated and *new* apps for 2.5 will be no longer allowed. [If you look at the table of differences for GAE, it certainly shows you can use 2.5](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27), just not everything is supported.

Just be sure your `app.yaml` uses:

```
runtime: python
```

Rather than `python27`, and you should be Ok.

[If you need a more definitive answer you can email Google](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2013/03/python-25-thanks-for-good-times.html).

Comment: +1 for emailing the developers. That should be the first thing you try actually.

Comment: Thanks. I emailed the developers. I'll post the answer back here when I get it. Right now I'm using 1.7.5, and it works.

Comment: I got an answer from Google, which I entered as the 'accepted answer'. This answer is actually incorrect: for SDK > 1.7.5 you need to use old_devappserver.py - see accepted answer for full details.

Answer (score 2):

The [1.8.2 release notes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.8.2_-_July_16,_2013) say that support for interpreter version 2.7.5 was added

> The Python Interpreter has been upgraded to 2.7.5.

but also seem to indicate that Python 2.5 is still supported:

> Fixed an issue with the Datastore bulkloader syntax when using the Python 2.5 interpreter.

There is no indication in the [release notes for version 1.8.3](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.8.3_-_August_6,_2013) (the most recent) that the support has been removed.

The notes [here](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2013/03/python-25-thanks-for-good-times.html) say that 2.5 is deprecated, but not yet removed:

> Starting from January 2014, we will no longer allow new applications to be created using the Python 2.5 runtime.